# Can't catch SIGINT in multithreaded program

Tags: python

I've seen many topics about this particular problem but i still can't figure why i'm not catching a SIGINT in my main Thread.

Here is my code:

```
def connect(self, retry=100):
    tries=retry
    logging.info('connecting to %s' % self.path)
    while True:
        try:
            self.sp = serial.Serial(self.path, 115200)
            self.pileMessage = pilemessage.Pilemessage()
            self.pileData = pilemessage.Pilemessage()
            self.reception = reception.Reception(self.sp,self.pileMessage,self.pileData)
            self.reception.start()
            self.collisionlistener = collisionListener.CollisionListener(self)
            self.message = messageThread.Message(self.pileMessage,self.collisionlistener)
            self.datastreaminglistener = dataStreamingListener.DataStreamingListener(self)
            self.datastreaming = dataStreaming.Data(self.pileData,self.datastreaminglistener)
            return
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            logging.info('retrying')
            if not retry:
                raise SpheroError('failed to connect after %d tries' % (tries-retry))
            retry -= 1



def disconnect(self):
    self.reception.stop()
    self.message.stop()
    self.datastreaming.stop()
    while not self.pileData.isEmpty():
        self.pileData.pop() 
    self.datastreaminglistener.remove()
    while not self.pileMessage.isEmpty():
        self.pileMessage.pop()
    self.collisionlistener.remove()
    self.sp.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
import time

try:
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    s = Sphero("/dev/rfcomm0")
    s.connect()
    s.set_motion_timeout(65525)
    s.set_rgb(0,255,0)
    s.set_back_led_output(255)
    s.configure_locator(0,0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.disconnect()
```

In the main function I call Connect() which is launching Threads over which i don't have direct controll. 
When I launch this script I would like to be able to stop it when hitting Control+C by calling the "disconnect()" function which stops all the other threads.

In the code i provided it doesn't work because there is no thread in the main function. But I already tryied putting all the instuctions from Main() in a Thread with a While loop without success.

Is there a simple way to solve my problem ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is messed up, but there's enough to go on.

Your main thread isn't catching `SIGINT` because *it's not alive*.  There is nothing that stops your main thread from continuing past the `try` block, seeing no more code, and closing up shop.

I am not familiar with `Sphero`.  I just attempted to google its docs and was linked to a bunch of 404 pages, so I'll tell you what you would normally do in a threaded environment - `join` your threads to the main thread so that the main thread can't finish execution before the worker threads.

```
for t in my_thread_list:
    t.join() #main thread can't get past here until all the threads finish
```

If your `Sphero` object doesn't provide `join`-like functionality, you could hack something in that blocks, i.e.

```
raw_input('Press Enter to disconnect')
s.disconnect()
```

Comment: My code is an extension of an existing Sphero Python API so for the threading part between the python threads we don't need to worry about if it's sphero or something else, I should threat it as in a normal threaded environnement as you say. The problem is that in my connect() function I launch the "reception" thread which represents the client  side (PC) running in banckground and waiting for sphero's messages. So I can't Join him to the main thread since the only way to stop him is by calling the disconnect() function called in the main thread. For the 2nd option I didn't really understand.